# How is the power calculated for Si(t) in the picture?

Tags: signal, communication

The formula I've seen is to multiply the signal by its complex conjugate, then integrate across the time period interval, and then divide by the period. But when I do that I don't get A^2/2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay. So why don't you get \$\displaystyle \frac{A^2}{2}?\$ It would be helpful to know what you did so that we can tell you where you were incorrect.

Comment: hi i posted my work and where im stuck

Comment: im confused...shouldn't those terms be 0 if the final answer is to be A^2/2?

Comment: isn't that the formula for power though?

Comment: Sorry, misread the question AGAIN. I deleted my wrong comments.

Comment: can u try and see what you get?

Comment: I'm stumped too =(. Sorry. For what it's worth, the computer did not give that answer either. I don't remember enough to help you at this point, but I do have to ask if A^2/2 is supposed to the solution inside the integral or after the integral is solved since the correct answer you posted is not within the integrals, but in your work it is assumed to be.

Answer (score 1):

The first image you posted appears to use Parseval's Relation after expressing the \$S_i(t)\$ as an exponential Fourier series.

Your method (the second image, I think) will produce the same answer, as long as you're careful about your limits of integration.  Let's assume that you've defined \$T_0 = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_c+\omega_m}\$.  Then your underlined terms can be recombined (using Euler "in reverse") to produce a cosine with frequency \$2(\omega_c+\omega_m)\$.  This cosine will complete two full oscillations in \$T_0\$ seconds, so its integral is zero.